# Voice Over: The UIButton's label is repeated when activated

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UIButton, when focus on the button, VoiceOver will speak the button's label, when double tap to activate it, VoiceOver will speak the button's label again.
Is there anyway I can prevent speaking the button's label again when double tapping the button?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: There's an answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578888/ios-voiceover-wait-on-element-to-finish-reading-before-changing-to-next-element

Comment: button.accessibilityTraits += UIAccessibilityTraitStartsMediaSession

Comment: the only problem with this is: if right after activating, if something is focused, it will not be spoken out

Comment: @munnie:  try and use the UIAccessibilityFocus informal protocol if you need to restore the button trait when the focus is lost ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#focus-an-element. That should help unless I didn't really understand your need. ‍